# Angular File Upload ( CORS ) with credentials is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using angular file module: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload.

I am facing difficulties in uploading to an api which requires credentials. I am passing 'withCredentials : true'. This doesn't seem to work.

I am able to successfully upload on another setup of same API without credentials.  CORS is set up properly on this API, other GET / POST calls ( CORS ) work on this API.

It would be great if you could guide me if I am missing something here.

Error :

"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - devices.olacabs-dev.in/notification/doUpload"; doUpload 2 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at hostname/notification/doUpload. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. I swapped with an API host not requiring credentials and that worked.

```js
  $upload.upload({
                    url: NotificationAPI.hostName + '/notification/doUpload',
                    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'},
                    fields: fields,
                    file: file,
                    withCredentials : true,
                }).
```

Comment: Do you have any console output, problems maybe network activity?

Comment: "NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - http://devices.olacabs-dev.in/notification/doUpload"
doUpload
2
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://hostname/notification/doUpload. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. I swapped with an API host not requiring credentials and that worked.

Comment: Are you using basic HTTP? Cookies? Header token? Looks like you must force it to upload

Comment: If you are using WebApi you should debug with Feddler. The real error it's been masked for the browser.

Comment: @Fals it it basic HTTP authentication at API.

Comment: @Rakesh as a said, the real issue has been masked for the browser. You should inspect deeper the request using Feddler to see the real error.

Comment: @Fals I am on mac :( any alternative ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74729/discussion-between-rakesh-and-fals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've just had the same issue as you. I solved it by setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' to true in the response headers.

Comment: how did you set this?

Comment: It depends on your environment. You could set it in your web server vhost config or have your server side application return it.